# comma in coffee script / framerjs

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

When do we use a comma after function declaration in coffee script?
For eg, in the code below why is there a comma after Events.DragStart?

`layerA.on Events.DragStart, ->
    print layerA.draggable.layerCursorOffset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma is not after the function declaration but after the first argument. Coffeescript is just a syntax for Javascript, so you can always compile it to Javascript to see what it does.

E.g. pasting your code snippet into the [js2.coffee](https://js2.coffee) web service yields this Javascript:

```
layerA.on(Events.DragStart, function() {
  return print(layerA.draggable.layerCursorOffset);
});
```